# How to configure JAVA_HOME for Selendroid

Tags: java, android, selendroid

From Selendroid's system requirements:

> Java SDK (minimum 1.6) must be installed and JAVA_HOME configured. IMPORTANT: If JAVA_HOME is pointing to a Java runtime environment, selendroid will produce errors because tools like the jarsigner are not available!

However, my $JAVA_HOME points to:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`

I believe this is the reason why i can't start Selendroid:

```
...
Apr 19, 2017 9:14:07 AM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /var/folders/np/gn2yjy916jjg33h2tr3hly3w0000gn/T/resigned-android-driver7285920814303014295.apk -storepass android -keystore /Users/cruz/.android/debug.keystore /var/folders/np/gn2yjy916jjg33h2tr3hly3w0000gn/T/android-driver7285920814303014295.apk androiddebugkey
Apr 19, 2017 9:14:07 AM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
SEVERE: Error executing command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /var/folders/np/gn2yjy916jjg33h2tr3hly3w0000gn/T/resigned-android-driver7285920814303014295.apk -storepass android -keystore /Users/cruz/.android/debug.keystore /var/folders/np/gn2yjy916jjg33h2tr3hly3w0000gn/T/android-driver7285920814303014295.apk androiddebugkey
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/jarsigner" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
...
```

Which path should I set in my `$JAVA_HOME`?

(Note: I am using Mac OS X 10.10.5)

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally figured out the path for JDK instead of JRE:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must get path where save content SDK.

Path: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/

If you've file .bash_profile, this write:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/
export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME
```